# What is the easiest way to store and query data without using a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fairly new to ASP.Net MVC, which is why I could use some direction.

I am building a site for a client that is not using a Database.

I have several (~20) youtube videos I would like to embed. The client is no longer producing these videos and this list will not be updated often. I have created a template view for the video and information. I would like to setup a model that can query a youtube video from the data set.

My initial thought is to create a JSON File, and a model class to query the information. Is that the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Use the Application Settings.

Comment: Sometimes plain old HTML still does the job

Comment: json sounds fine to me, but I wonder what kind of queries you'll run. You might find static html, maybe with a google custom search engine, does the job just as well or better than going data-driver here.

Comment: Why?  I'm trying to figure out why you don't just use an off the shelf CMS with a page template that they can just plug the youtube video location in?  Seems like this would be better served going that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON seems like a great idea to me. With only about 20 records total, you're near the point where it doesn't even make sense to be data driven: just have 20 static pages with shared css and google custom search engine for queries. However, I still tend to prefer relying on a data source whenever I can, and I like JSON for this.

JSON will work well here because you can use a *.js file that will be cached by most browsers, and you can execute your searches on data without even needing to refresh the page. Especially if you're using a templating system like Knockout or Ember, you can have this be entirely a client application: no server code. Such an application would be **very** fast from the user perspective, especially if you use a cdn for the template engine, such that many users will already have it cached on first load.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML document to store structured data, load it, and use XPath to query it (be mindful of XPath Injection vulnerabilities).  Or use the same XML to deserialize into a data model and use LINQ to query it.

(B/w, this is by far not the only option - just one-and-a-half that comes immediately to mind)

Answer (score 0):

I would put the data in flat text file of my preferred format (personally json also) and then I would deserialize that into a list of objects and use LINQ queries on it. Given the small amount of data in question I would use a flat file in favor of a database even if I had the option.

You could also use a resx file as part of the project or the in built settings as suggested in the comments. Regardless of how you do it, the amount of data is small enough that you may as well just read it into a collection in memory and then query that collection.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't need to be updated very often, an easy approach would be to just create a hard coded list in code that's used to generate links from. If you want to be able to update the links in the future without modifying code then XML or JSON are likely your best bets.